# Highlight UITableViewCell on touch event in a composite UIView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4.3, uistoryboard

I have a UITableViewCell which is made up of a child container UIView and some other child components, such as labels, background, icons, etc...
Each UIImageView has also an highlight image set in Xcode IB.

The cell is assembled in a UIStoryBoard and has a segue connected to it, therefore I am not using the typical didSelect method of delegate.
This is the hierarchy:

```
UIViewController (serving as UITableView delegate)
--> UIView (main view)
    --> UITableView
        --> UItableViewCell
            --> UIView
                --> (several UIView, image, label, etc..)
```

I wonder how can I have my cell selected in this scenario. It is fine for me to highlight the whole cell, but I am also interested in knowing how to make a specific select.

For select/highlighting I mean, forget the standard blue or grey selection, but rather, recall all those specific images I mark as 'highlighted' in IB.

Platform target is iOS 5.

thanks

Comment: You have a `UITableViewCell` in your storyboard, not inside any kind of controller?

Comment: yes, an UITableViewCell in a UITableView.

Comment: It's inside a table view controller then? It sounds like you just need to subclass it.

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but it's just a UIViewController set as delegate and datasource. Not a UITableViewController.

Comment: So you want to highlight this composite table cell when the user touches inside of a specific part of it?

Comment: I have just added few explanation, see if it helps.

Comment: It looks like you need to pass a message to the cell in the table view delegate's didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: As I specified in the question, I am using storyboard, so I wasn't in need of didSelectRow... but if it is the only solution !! What kind of 'message' are you talking about ? Try to write down an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UIViewController file should implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

```
@interface NameOfViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Then you can override the table's methods. It sounds like you want to override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. I'm still a little unclear on exactly what you want to do, but it sounds like you will just use this method and either tell the cell it's highlighted or pass a message to the cell telling it to do something (like change its images). You will also need to subclass your cell and load it from a .xib file if you want to do this. Sorry if this sounds like a lot of work, but table views require a lot of code for customization beyond very basic stuff.

Comment: yes, the only solution seems to be calling mybackground.highlight=YES, and so on, and this has to be done in didSelectRow...